# iconv: Convert from CP1252 to UTF-8

Tags: iconv

I'm trying to convert the CP1252 encoded string Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà to UTF-8. I have tried this command:

```
iconv -c -f=WINDOWS-1252 -t=UTF-8 test.txt
```

No luck, getting some weird results:

ÃŠÃ€Ã‡Ã€ÃÃœ ÃÃŽÃ‚Ã›Ã‰ Ã‚Ã…ÃŠ

I tried entering the same string (Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà) here, and they are able to convert it without problems:
http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 30):

When you convert CP1252 encoded string `Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà` to UTF-8 with command `iconv.exe -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 test.txt >testout.txt` then the source file `test.txt` (Hex view:

[image]

) will be converted into target file `testout.txt` (Hex view:

[image]

) which is UTF-8 code for `Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà`.

Same garbage you put in will come the other end out. iconv's behavior is correct and as expected.

What you are perplexed by is that you don't see what you expect and that is because your input 8bit string is actually encoded in [Windows-1251 (Cyrillic) Codepage](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepages.php?codepage=windows-1251).

→ So the correct code page is not CP125**<del>2</del>** but CP125**1** ←

[image]

Command `iconv.exe -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 test.txt >testout2.txt` converts the source file `test.txt` into target file `testout2.txt` (Hex view:

[image]

) which is UTF-8 code for `Записки экспедитора` which is what your user's expect to see

Answer (score 9):

You ned to use this one:

```
$ echo "Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà" | iconv -t latin1 | iconv -f cp1251
Записки экспедитора
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP specifically asked about converting from CP1252 encoding to UTF-8, and your command uses neither encoding.

Comment: @Edward the string OP provided is in cp1251, not cp1252, I think he have made a mistake in this part

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 in.file -o out.file
```

Comment: Not working too :) for Çàïèñêè ýêñïåäèòîðà gives Ã‡Ã Ã¯Ã¨Ã±ÃªÃ¨ Ã½ÃªÃ±Ã¯Ã¥Ã¤Ã¨Ã²Ã®Ã°Ã

Answer (score 0):

if you're using linux you should use [enconv](http://github.com/thiagoh/enconv)

```
./enconv.sh -d /home/foo/example/directory -e ".java" -f "iso-8859-1" -t "utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 file.php | iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 > file-utf8.php
```

Comment: please remember to write some explanation.

Comment: it is THE command that works for me. The original actions to reproduce warped text are : make some proper cp-1251 textfile, and open it as cp-1252. The utf-8 is just the native universal codepage of the system, so we use it for fringe input and output. Bash pipe and stdout redirection you may figure out on your own

Comment: The essense of what we do here is the  CP1252 --> CP1251  re-interpretation.

Answer (score -1):

try the opposite

```
  iconv -c -f=UTF-8 -t=WINDOWS-1252 test.txt
```