# Delphi/windows and Linux/Lazarus sharing character above #127

Tags: linux, windows, delphi, character-encoding, lazarus

I am maintaining a project where data has to be shared between windows and linux machines.
The program has been developed in DELPHI (Windows) in 2003 - so there is a lot of legacy data files that must be (at least probably) read by both systems in the future.

I have ported the programm to Lazarus and it runs on Linux quite well.

But the data (in a proprietary format) has stored strings as general ascii-characters from #0-#255. Reading the data on a linux machine leads to a lot of '?'-Symbols instead of 'ñ,äöüß...' etc.

What I tried to solve the problem:

1.) I read the data on a windows machine - as usual.
2.) I saved the data with a modified version, that will encode all strings with URLEncode()
    on saving.
3.) I also modified the routine reading the data with URLDecode
4.) I saved the data with the modified version.
5.) I compiled the modiefied version on linux and copied the data from the windows machine.
6.) I opened the data in question ... and got questionmarks (?) instead of 'ñ,äöüß...' etc.

Well, the actual question is: How to share the data maintained by both systems and preserving those characters when editing the data (on both sides)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any chances to retrofit with UTF-8? And important note: ASCII range ends with #127.

Comment: ASCII is a 7 bit character set. With ordinals in the range 0 to 127. So the values above 127 are not ASCII. You'll need to understand what they are. Likely Windows ANSI. You are probably interpreting as UTF-8 when loading under Linux. The smart move would be to switch from ANSI to UTF-8. Step 1 is to learn what Unicode is.

Comment: Knowing **exactly** what is the meaning of the bytes that you see as question marks is a must. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866775/2626313 answer shows how you can diagnose what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**8bit Ansi** values between 128-255 are **charset-specific**.  Whatever charset is used to save the data on Windows (assuming you are relying on Windows default encoding, which is dependent on the user's locale), you have to use that same charset when loading the data on Linux, and vice versa.  There are dozens, if not hundreds, of charsets used in the world, which makes portability of Ansi data difficult. This is exactly the kind of problem that Unicode was designed to address.  You are best off saving your data in a portable charset, such as UTF-8, and then perform conversions to/from the system charset when loading/saving the data.

Comment: The problem is/will be: There are still Windows users working with the programm. The latest Windows executable was created with BDS2006 which is not Unicode-aware. A more recent version of Delphi is not available. So converting all data-files is easy to write but it will not be a solution.

Comment: @hy-soft Be aware that you are confusing Unicode and UTF-16. If you use UTF-8 encoding in BDS2006 string or on file (as Remy suggested), your business code will be perfectly Unicode aware. The VCL itself is tied to the system code page, due to Windows restriction which never implemented UTF-8 at the system level, whereas Linux did make the choice of UTF-8 for full Unicode support of its API, using regular 8 bit char wide. Some code refactoring to use UTF-8 encoding for storage is the solution - and perhaps use a portable file format, like SQlite3 - see http://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudBouchez I will give it a try - but I will not be able to try until tonight (GMT).

Comment: @hy-soft: just because you are using a pre-Unicode version of Delphi DOES NOT mean you cannot work with Unicode data. You can use `WideString` to hold UTF-16 encoded text in memory, and you can use the RTL's `UTF8Encode()` and `UTF8Decode()` functions when saving/loading your data. And you can use third-party controls, like TNTWare, if you need to work with Unicode in your UI.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau that is a VERY good hint. Today I hope to have time to test it - and will give some feedback.

Comment: Ok UTF8Encode/UTF8Decode got me the desired results. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using UTF-8 for [all your text storage](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Or, if you are sure that your data will always have the same code page, you can use conversion from the original Windows code page to UTF-8, which is the default Linux/Lazarus encoding.

You should better not rely on any proprietary binary layout for your application file format, if you want it to be cross-platform. You just discovered the character encoding problem, but you have potentially other issues, like binary endianess. SQLite3 is a very good [application file format](http://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html). It is fast, reliable, cross-platform, stable and atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Lazarus **always** expects **utf8** strings for GUI. So even on Windows this probably wouldn't work without proper utf8 sanitation